# How to make following C# code for splitting a path string efficient?

Tags: c#

I have the following C# method to split a path string.
Only thing I know is a fixed string in the path and I have to split the full path into two parts, first part should be one level below the fixed string and the rest should be the second part.
For example, if I have the following path,

```
 string mainText = @"C:\Abc\Fixed\MyTemp\Japan\Tokyo";
```

then my firstPart would be `"C:\Abc\Fixed\MyTemp"` and second part `"Japan\Tokyo"`

I want to improve this method in terms of memory and speed.

```
private static void SplitPath(string mainText, out string firstPart, out string secondPart)
        {
            firstPart = string.Empty;
            secondPart = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainText))
            {
                string strConstatnt = "Fixed";
                List<string> splitted = mainText.Split(new char[] { '\\' }).ToList();
                int indexToFixed = splitted.IndexOf(strConstatnt);
                StringBuilder sbFirst = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder sbSecond = new StringBuilder();
                if (indexToFixed >= 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < (indexToFixed + 2))
                        {
                            sbFirst.Append(splitted[i] + "\\");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = (indexToFixed + 2); i < splitted.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sbSecond.Append(splitted[i] + "\\");
                    }
                }
                if (sbFirst.Length > 0)
                {
                    firstPart = sbFirst.Remove(sbFirst.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
                }
                if (sbSecond.Length > 0)
                {
                    secondPart = sbSecond.Remove(sbSecond.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing code. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Does the current implementation prove any problems? Do you have a specific location which you think you can improve? Or is this "here is my code, improve it"? Then that's offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building the result using for loops and `StringBuilder` you can use `String.Join` to combine the parts in `splitted`:

```
firstPart = String.Join(@"\", splitted.Take(indexToFixed + 2);
secondPart = String.Join(@"\", splitted.Skip(indexToFixed + 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little sample (assuming you want to split after Fixed):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = @"C:\Abc\Fixed\MyTemp\Japan\Tokyo";
    foreach (var item in Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=Fixed\\(?=[^\\]+))"))
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```